# URLs containing colons are escaped and do not resolve

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

#### The problem

While writing [my last
answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130399/5245) I noticed that
linking to external resources containing a colon does not work,
since the colon is being escaped as `%3a` and thus mangled and the
URLs do not resolve any longer.

#### Example

[`https://gitorious.org/context/context/source/b76759d73e6734cb014fe46da1f8521dcc9a8d71:metapost/context/base/mp-mlib.mpiv#L182-256`](https://gitorious.org/context/context/source/b76759d73e6734cb014fe46da1f8521dcc9a8d71:metapost/context/base/mp-mlib.mpiv#L182-256)

#### Analysis

I tried to link to external resources using the markdown syntax
`[description](URL)`. The URL contained unescaped colons. After
having read the [RFC - Uniform Resource
Identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) I hold that colons
do not have to be escaped and that this is a bug in the
stackexchange code, rather than a fault on the external resources'
side.

Colons are listed as [reserved
characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-12). The
relevant section is:

> URI producing applications should percent-encode data octets that
> correspond to characters in the reserved set unless these characters
> are specifically allowed by the URI scheme to represent data in that
> component.  If a reserved character is found in a URI component and
> no delimiting role is known for that character, then it must be
> interpreted as representing the data octet corresponding to that
> character's encoding in US-ASCII.

Take this URL:

```
https://gitorious.org/context/context/source/b76759d73e6734cb014fe46da1f8521dcc9a8d71:metapost/context/base/mp-mlib.mpiv#L182-256
```

According to [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) the colon
belongs to the *path* part:

> ```
>   foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
>   \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
>    |           |            |            |        |
> scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
>    |   _____________________|__
>   / \ /                        >       urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
> ```

Furthermore, the path is of type
[path-absolute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3),
which requires the syntax `path-absolute = "/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ]` with `segment-nz = 1*pchar` and `segment = *pchar` and
`pchar = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"`.

This means, the path can contain all unreserved characters, encoded
characters or colons, if I'm not mistaken.

#### Workaround

For the time being an URL shortener can be used and the shortened
URL can be included. However, this is generally not desirable.

#### Discussion

I don't know why stackexchange alters the link in the first place.
As far as I know, the parentheses enclose an URL, which is only
valid if has been properly encoded by the user. No further encoding
is required.

**EDIT:** It was indeed a bug on gitorious side. And Marcin [committed a fix](https://gitorious.org/gitorious/mainline/commit/b4288cb228dbce734acfdc0701f5085e74c3ced9) today, which has already been released, so the link mentioned above resolves correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe there's an [answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88655/1438) that addresses the issue.  The important bit is:

> A colon and `%3a` are semantically identical in URLs per the RFC.

If you look at an [example on Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/20783/10037) (and read the comments), you'll see that the problem should actually be fixed by the site that serves pages with colons in the URL.  This is actually a bug at Gitorious.org.  If you notice, the server returns with `500 Internal server error`:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> Gitorious encountered an server error. We are automatically notified of errors and will look into it. If the error persists beyond what's reasonable, [let us know](https://gitorious.org/contact).

The reason for encoding seems to be that failing to do so [breaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17077/1438) refernce-style [links in Markdown](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links).  Your solution of using a link shortener seems the best workaround.